# PHP5 versus PHP7.0

Tags: php

I have two programs written in PHP that have been running fine in Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS with PHP5. Now I am trying to run them on a new installation of Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS with PHP7.0.  Each asks for a user nane and password, then blows up, but in different ways. Is there any online documentation on the incompatabilities between PHP5 and PHP7.0?

One says "new PDO() threw an exception", the other complains "Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND'".

Comment: This seems to be a question that is specific to PHP rather than Ubuntu.

Comment: yes - type "php 7" into google - [Migrating from PHP 5.6.x to PHP 7.0.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php) is the first result

Answer (score 2):

Looks like php-mysql package is missing for php 7. Try installing it with:

```
sudo apt install php7.0-mysql
```

If package could not be found:

```
sudo apt install python-software-properties
sudo LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-7.0
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.0-mysql
```

Comment: Thank you. Installed at 7pm. I will test it in the morning (now sleepy)

Comment: Good night :) don't forget to restart web server before testing

Comment: Now powered off; will power up at dawn.

Comment: A weakness in Ubuntu. "apt install php" gave me the PHP7.0 package. "apt install mysql-server" and "apt install mysql-client" gave my the mysql packages. But nothing gave me the php7.0-mysql package I needed to bridge them.

Comment: The package you told me to install, php7.0-mysql, does not seem to fixed the problem.  Get the user name and password, then crash

# 
# --- new PDO() threw an exception
# E = (object) object(PDOException)#3 (8) { ["message":protected]=> string(90) "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'grosemat'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(1045) ["file":protected]=> string(33) "/data/fasemat/Site/include/DB.inc" ["line":protected]=> int(242) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(33) "/

Comment: It actually should fix issue with MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND and undefined PDO. The exeption says that you have problems connecting to database. Is mysql running on localhost? Can you login to mysql with grosemat user and password?